# change status of each ordered Products

Tags: magento-1.9, database, javascript, drop-downs

we are displaying orders in custom orders.php page in **www.1234.com/site6/orders.php**

I am trying to change status of each order from **Paid to unpaid** & viceversa.....

i can select required status & click on "submit" button & but it displaying error  "NO record selected"....

[image]

[image]

**php**

```
function getDesignerCollection()
    {

    $user_home = new USER();    
    $i = 0;

    foreach($order as $orderData) 
{ 
$k = 0; 
$orderitems = $orderData['dproduct_id']; 
$orderitemsarray = explode(",", $orderitems); 

while ($k < count($orderitemsarray)) 
{ 

if ($orderitemsarray[$k] != '0') 
{ 
$stmtorders = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT * FROM order_details");  
$roworders = $stmtorders->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print_r($roworders);    

if($data['type']=="admin")continue; 
if($data['dpaid_status']==''){$dpaid_status='';}
if($data['dpaid_status']=='P'){$dorderStatus='Paid';} 
if($data['dpaid_status']=='U'){$dorderStatus='Unpaid';} 


if ($roworders[ 

'dproduct_id'] == '') 
{ 
$dorderStatus = "Unpaid"; 
} 
else 
{ 
$dorderStatus = $roworders['dpaid_status']; 
} 

$k++; 
$i++; 
} 
}

    echo json_encode($responce);
    }
```

**form**

```
<form  action='' method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       <input type="hidden" name="delete_package_id" id="delete_package_id" value=""/>
       Action:

    <select name="massaction" id="massaction">
           <option value="">Select</option>
           <option value="P">Paid</option>
           <option value="U">Unpaid</option>
    </select>

        <input type="button" value="Submit" id="delete-grid-button" onclick="massAction()" />
    </form>
```

**script**

```
function massAction()
{
    var e=document.getElementById("massaction");
    var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

    massStatusChangeVerified(strUser);

}


function massStatusChangeVerified(status)
    {       
        var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('dorder_id');   
        var vals = "";      
        for (var i=0, n=checkboxes.length;i<n;i++) {
          if (checkboxes[i].checked) 
          {
          vals += ","+checkboxes[i].value;
          }
        }
        if(vals=='')
        {
            alert("No record selected");
            return false;
        }
        retactiveVal=confirm("Are you sure want to Change the status");
        if( retactiveVal == true )
        {
        if (vals) vals = vals.substring(1);     
        document.getElementsByName('delete_package_id').value=vals;     
        var url="http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/php/site6/update_order_status.php?designer_id="+vals+"&order_status="+status;
           var request = jQuery.ajax( {
                url: url ,
                type: 'POST',                      
            } );

            request.done( function (result)
            {  
                document.getElementById('msgresult').style.display="block";
                var explode = function(){
                 location.reload();
                };
                setTimeout(explode, 2000);


            } );
            request.fail( function ( error )
            {
                console.dir(error);             
            } );return true;
            }else{                   
              return false;
        }       
    }
```

[image]

script reuslts for creating grid :

```
function my_renderId(value ,record,columnObj,grid,colNo,rowNo)
{
    var no= record[columnObj.fieldIndex];

    return "<input type='checkbox' value='"+record[0]+"' name='userID'/>";
}


    var colsOption = [
        {id: '' , header: "" , width :"15",renderer : my_renderId , width :"60"},
        {id: 'created_at' , header: "Order Date" , width :"120"},
        {id: 'entity_id' , header: "Order Id" , width :"75"},    
        {id: 'dpaid_status' , header: "Paid status" , width :"80"},
    ];
```

**Edit** : updateorderstatus.php

```
if( isset($_GET['order_status']) && !empty($_GET['order_status']) && $_GET['order_status']!="" )
    {  $staus=$_GET['order_status']; }else{ $staus="";}

    if( isset($_GET['designer_id']) && !empty($_GET['designer_id']) && $_GET['designer_id']!="" )
    {  $allCheckedBoxes=$_GET['designer_id'];  }
    else{ $allCheckedBoxes="";} 
    $ArrallCheckedBoxes=explode(",",$allCheckedBoxes);
    if(isset($conVar) && !empty($conVar) && $conVar!=""){       
        foreach($ArrallCheckedBoxes as $tempBoxes){
                $sqlQueryToUpdate=" UPDATE order_details SET dpaid_status = '".$staus."'  WHERE userID = '".$tempBoxes."' ;";
                $sucessFlag=mysqli_query($conVar,$sqlQueryToUpdate);
                    if($sucessFlag==TRUE){
                    echo "Records Updated Sucessfully.";
                }else{
                    echo " Record already Updated.";
                }
            } 
    }
```

Comment: I  think there should be some other problem then this

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala really not getting where went wrong, you may be right,....

Comment: got the point send me example of one input type check box for  `dorder_id`

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala pls check  updated  question with db table.....

Comment: I am talking about the checkbox html code for `dorder_id`

Comment: I am talking about the checkboxes that you have in grid

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala looks like you want this : `return "<input type='checkbox' value='"+record[0]+"' name='userID'/>";`

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala pls check  complete code here : http://pastebin.com/kieFt0g2

Comment: there is no code for your grid please provide me the code which is responsible for creating the grid

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala please check bottom part in question, i updated script , that is only results for creating grid.....

Comment: Try to inspect element from browser and check what is the name of check-box of grid.

Comment: @AshishJagnani pls check : http://prnt.sc/divh0p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reckon use the jquery for that

```
 var vals = ""; 
            var checkboxes=$("input[name='userID[]']:checked").each( function () {

          vals += ","+$(this).val();

                            })
                 alert(vals);
```

change the name in `userID` to `userID[]`

```
    function my_renderId(value ,record,columnObj,grid,colNo,rowNo)
     {
        var no= record[columnObj.fieldIndex];

        return "<input type='checkbox' value='"+record[0]+"-"+record[3]+' name='userID[]'/>";
     }
```

updateorderstatus.php

```
if( isset($_GET['order_status']) && !empty($_GET['order_status']) && $_GET['order_status']!="" )
    {  $staus=$_GET['order_status']; }else{ $staus="";}

    if( isset($_GET['designer_id']) && !empty($_GET['designer_id']) && $_GET['designer_id']!="" )
    {  $allCheckedBoxes=$_GET['designer_id'];  }
    else{ $allCheckedBoxes="";} 
    $ArrallCheckedBoxes=explode(",",$allCheckedBoxes);
    if(isset($conVar) && !empty($conVar) && $conVar!=""){       
        foreach($ArrallCheckedBoxes as $tempBoxes){

             $newtempBoxes=explode('-',$tempBoxes);

                $sqlQueryToUpdate=" UPDATE order_details SET dpaid_status = '".$staus."'  WHERE userID = '".$tempBoxes."' and designerorder_id = '".$newtempBoxes[0]."' and dproduct_id = '".$newtempBoxes[1]."' ";
                $sucessFlag=mysqli_query($conVar,$sqlQueryToUpdate);
                    if($sucessFlag==TRUE){
                    echo "Records Updated Sucessfully.";
                }else{
                    echo " Record already Updated.";
                }
            } 
    }
```

as reference to this [question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/150294/merge-results-of-magento-and-custom-database-with-while-loop/150297#150297)

Comment: okay i will check & let you know....

Comment: its working, but once i get solution for this : http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/149411/values-are-not-fetching-from-database than only i can check correctly, once you get free time, please help me for that link.....

Comment: status changing working on order basis not on per product basis.... if we change status for " `order id - 100000138 , product id - 15515`" it should work only for this product id, but now its changing for other
product ids also related to that order....

Comment: in your updated code, you missed closing "[double quotes] , so it was displaying blank, now i changed that as `return "<input type='checkbox' value='"+record[0]+"-"+record[3]+"' name='userID[]'/>";`  now table is displaying, but `status changing is not working.....

Comment: @BabyinMagento is ajax is working? can you share url of your ajax call

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace this code

```
var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('dorder_id');
```

with this on everywhere

```
var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('userID');
```

remove my second change of link and replace this

```
$sqlQueryToUpdate=" UPDATE order_details SET dpaid_status = '".$staus."'  WHERE userID = '".$tempBoxes."' ;";
```

with :

```
$sqlQueryToUpdate=" UPDATE order_details SET dpaid_status = '".$staus."'  WHERE designerorder_id = '".$tempBoxes."' ;";
```

Comment: `no receord selected` error gone, now i need to update the values in database, but that is not happening, please help me.....

Comment: updated, still its not changing values, please check link once

Comment: updated question with update_order_status.php file ,  i replaced with this code : `var url="http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/php/site6/update_order_status.php?designer_id=<?php echo $_SESSION['userSession'];?>&order_status="+status;`

Comment: in `view page source` displaying : `var url="http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/php/site6/update_order_status.php?designer_id=3&order_status="+status;` that is `3`, that  is correct value of designer id

Comment: also if you want to check, this is full code : http://pastebin.com/s8waxhA5

Comment: please check question, i posted image of DB.....

Comment: @BabyinMagento, check updated answer

Comment: now i replaced `var url="http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/php/site6/update_order_status.php?designer_id=<?php echo $_SESSION['userSession'];?>&order_status="+status;` with `var url="http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/php/site6/update_order_status.php?designer_id="+vals+"&order_status="+status;` & also updated `updateorderstatus.php` file , still its showing `unpaid` only.....

Comment: `var url="http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/php/site6/update_order_status.php?designer_id=3&order_status="+status;`

Comment: @BabyinMagento, there is some mistake. use this url : `url="http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/php/site6/update_order_st‌​atus.php?designer_id‌​="+vals+"&order_stat‌​us="+status; & also updated updateorderstatus.php` and check again

Comment: i updated new url ,   now i am not getting message : `Paid status changed` once i click on submit button , also i please tell is there any changes i need to do in `updateorderstatus.php`

Comment: in view page source its displaying like this : `var url="http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/php/site6/update_order_stâ€Œâ€‹â€Œâ€‹atus.php?designer_â€Œâ€‹idâ€Œâ€‹="+vals+"&order_â€Œâ€‹statâ€Œâ€‹us="+status;`

Comment: @BabyinMagento, instead of copy past, Type this url code in notepad and put again in code file.

Comment: sure.. i will do

Comment: now `var url="http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/php/site6/update_order_status.php?designer_id="+vals+"&order_status="+status;` and gettign message once i click on `submit` button.....

Comment: getting message once i click on `submit` button..... but `status` is not changing`

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50027/discussion-on-answer-by-ashish-jagnani-change-status-of-each-ordered-products).