# values are not fetching from database

Tags: magento-1.9, database

We are trying to fetch value from custom database & display related value for all rows [orders] .

but code is fetching only **first row** value in DB & displaying same value for **all rows**.

**Database**

[image]

**Site**

[image]

```
     foreach($order as $orderData) 
    { 
    $k = 0; 
    $orderitems = $orderData['dproduct_id']; 
    $orderitemsarray = explode(",", $orderitems); 

    while ($k < count($orderitemsarray)) 
    { 

    if ($orderitemsarray[$k] != '0') 
    { 
    $stmtorders = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT * FROM order_details"); 
    $stmtorders->execute(array(":dorder_id" => $orderData['dorder_id']));
  // $stmtorders->execute(array(":dorder_id" => $orderData['entity_id'])); 
    $roworders = $stmtorders->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

    if($data['type']=="admin")continue; 

    if($data['dpaid_status']=='P'){$dorderStatus='Paid';} 
    if($data['dpaid_status']=='U'){$dorderStatus='Unpaid';} 
    if($data['dpaid_status']=='R'){$dorderStatus='Returned';} 
    if($data['dpaid_status']==''){$dpaid_status='';} 

    if ($roworders[ 

    'dproduct_id'] == '') 
    { 
    $dorderStatus = "Unpaid"; 
    } 
    else 
    { 
    $dorderStatus = $roworders['dpaid_status']; 
    } 

    $productdetail = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($orderitemsarray[$k]); 
    $designer_id = $productdetail->getDesignerID() ; 

    if($accountType == "admin"){ 
    $designerName = getDesignerName($productdetail->getDesignerID()) . " -(" . $productdetail->getDesignerID() . ")"; 
    $responce[] = array( 
    $dorderStatus 
    ); 
    }

    else
    { 
    if( $designer_id== $_SESSION['userSession'] ){ 
    $designerName = getDesignerName($productdetail->getDesignerID()) . " -(" . $productdetail->getDesignerID() . ")"; 
    $responce[] = array( 
    $dorderStatus
    ); 
    } 
    }
    }

    $k++; 
    $i++; 
    } 
    }

    echo json_encode($responce);
```

full code : http://pastebin.com/gn4paZWM

Comment: What is `$order` ?? in foreach loop

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala when i tried `print $order;` it didt displayed anything.....

Comment: please post the code before this foreach where you assign the values of `$order`

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala this is related code : http://pastebin.com/DLDxqhCw  & this is full code : http://pastebin.com/17U2i2eH

Comment: please provide all fields of `order_details` tables

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala pls check it buddy : http://prnt.sc/dirfoe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as reference to this [question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/150294/merge-results-of-magento-and-custom-database-with-while-loop/150297#150297) you need to check `dproduct_id` and `designerorder_id` against every product.

```
$stmt1 = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT * FROM order_details WHERE dproduct_id=:pid and designerorder_id=:doid");
    $stmt1->execute(array(
        ":doid" => $orderData->getIncrementId(),
        ":pid" => $orderitemsarray[$k],
    ));
    $paid_status='';
    while($datas = $stmt1->fetch())

{
    $paid_status=$datas['dpaid_status'];

}
$responce[] = array( 
$paid_status 
);
```

Comment: I did some modifications to your code & seems its working now, Thanks....

Answer (score 1):

AS Far as I know change this line

```
 $stmtorders->execute(array(":dorder_id" => $orderData['dorder_id']));
```

TO

```
 $stmtorders->execute(array(":dorder_id" => $orderData['entity_id']));
```

and also change this

```
$stmtorders = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT * FROM order_details  WHERE dorder_id=:do_id");
$stmtorders->execute(array(":do_id" => $orderData['entity_id'])); 
$roworders = $stmtorders->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print_r($roworders);
```

Comment: sorry, not working for me.....

Comment: pls check this is related code : http://pastebin.com/iGBMuPHg

Comment: when i tried `print_r($order);` order table disappeared......

Comment: i tried updated code : `$stmtorders = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT * FROM order_details WHERE dorder_id=:dorder_id");` still order table not displaying......

Comment: sorry, table is not displaying now......

Comment: now for all rows its displaying value = `unpaid` , this is fine , but also for values which present in DB, for that it should display `paid or unpaid`,  for  `print_r($roworders); ` didt displaed anything

Comment: its looking like : http://prnt.sc/dirkuz

Comment: when i tried `echo $orderData['entity_id'];` it hide the table values......

Comment: this is full updated code : http://pastebin.com/xd7Kex8B

Comment: @BabyinMagento do echo before the while loop

Comment: when i tried `echo $orderData['entity_id'];

while ($k < count($orderitemsarray)) ` still its not displaying any rows....

Comment: @BabyinMagento `print_r($orderData);`

Comment: values [rows]  are still not displaying for `print_r($orderData);`

Comment: you can see : http://prnt.sc/dit4i8

Comment: @BabyinMagento  change $order object as below

Comment: $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('designer_id', array(
'like' => '%' . $_SESSION['userSession'] . '%'
))
->addAttributeToSelect('designer_id')
->addAttributeToSelect('created_at')
->addAttributeToSelect('dproduct_id')
->addAttributeToSelect('customer_id')
->addAttributeToSelect('increment_id')
->addAttributeToSelect('updated_at')
->addAttributeToSelect('status')
->addAttributeToSelect('entity_id')
->addAttributeToSelect('state');

Comment: sory, still its not displaying any rows.....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50014/discussion-between-baby-in-magento-and-murtuza-zabuawala).

Comment: @BabyinMagento You are always welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$stmtorders = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT * FROM order_details"); 
$stmtorders->execute(array(":dorder_id" => $orderData['dorder_id'])); 
$roworders = $stmtorders->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

This will always get you the first row because you are always executing `SELECT * FROM order_details` with no `where` statement and because `fetch` always returns one row. You should call it in a `while` loop if you expect more rows.

So make your code like this (adapt it to your needs because I don't really understand what it should do).

```
$stmtorders = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT * FROM order_details WHERE dorder_id = :dorder_id"); 
$stmtorders->execute(array(":dorder_id" => $orderData['dorder_id'])); 
while ($roworders = $stmtorders->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    //do something with $roworders
}
```

Comment: Thanks for support, i will check & come back to you.....