# Merge results of magento and custom Database with while loop

Tags: magento-1.9

We have 2 while loops , we are displaying 2 different results with both.

we need to **combine** or without combining we need to merge 2 results.

in below image ,

**1st while** loop result = >  1st, 2nd, 6th rows.

**2nd while** loop result = >  3rd, 4th, 5th rows.

we need 3rd , 4th & 5th rows results in **1st, 2nd 6th rows last column** [ Paid status ].

1st while results coming from Database 1 [ magento - `sales_flat_order`] & 2nd while results are coming from Database 2 with table name `order_details`

[image]

[image]

```
$stmt = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT * FROM order_details");  
$stmt->execute(array(":uid" => $_SESSION['userSession']));
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$stmt->execute();

$i = 0; 

foreach($order as $orderData) 
{ 
$k = 0; 
$orderitems = $orderData['dproduct_id']; 
$orderitemsarray = explode(",", $orderitems); 

/* 1st while */
while ($k < count($orderitemsarray))    
{ 

if ($orderitemsarray[$k] != '0') 
{ 

$stmtorders = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT * FROM order_details"); 
$stmtorders->execute(array(":dorder_id" => $orderData['entity_id'])); 
$roworders = $stmtorders->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
$dorderStatus = $roworders['dpaid_status']; 

$productdetail = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($orderitemsarray[$k]); 
$designer_id = $productdetail->getDesignerID() ; 

if($accountType == "admin")
{ 
$designerName = getDesignerName($productdetail->getDesignerID()) . " -(" . $productdetail->getDesignerID() . ")"; 

$responce[] = array( 
$orderData->getIncrementId() ,  
$orderitemsarray[$k], 
$productdetail->getName() , 
$designerName, 
$orderData['status'],                 
$data['dpaid_status'],
$data['commission'],
$sDate                             
); 

}
}

$k++; 
$i++; 
} 

/* 2nd while */

while($data = $stmt->fetch())   
{   

$responce[] = array( 
$data['dorder_id'],
$data['dpaid_status'],
$data['commission']
); 
$k++;
}   
}
```

I tried below code , but it results as below image - means only 2 rows displayed instead of 23 rows....

```
while (($k < count($orderitemsarray)) &&  ($data = $stmt->fetch()))
```

[image]

Full page looks as below :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simple solution is that  add before first while loop

```
$response=array();

  foreach($order as $orderData) 
 { 
    $response=array('dfj'=>'dfd');
 }
```

then second loop

```
while($data = $stmt->fetch()) 
 { 
    $response=array('dfj'=>'dfd');
 }
```

at the end `return $response;`

second way is array merge

```
 $response=array();

  foreach($order as $orderData) 
 { 
    $responce=array('dfj'=>'dfd');
 }
```

then second loop

```
while($data = $stmt->fetch()) 
 { 
    $responce1=array('dfj'=>'dfd');
 }

 $result = array_merge($responce, $responce1);
```

at the end `return $result;`

Comment: what i did is i used `$responce[] = array(......); ` code before `foreach` & at the end i used this code :  `return $response;` but didt worked for me. can you please update answer with more details , i am not expert like you.....

Comment: what `print_r($responce);` will give you after first loop? then check it after second loop.

Comment: order gird is not displaying, `print_r($responce);` displaying nothing,  if you can update with full code , that will be much better......

Comment: @BabyinMagento use exit after that

Comment: i tried `exit("nothing displaying");` , but still table[ order grid] is not displaying.....